# Error when try to open contacts

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am building an app using objective-c.
when I press button that linked to func that should open the contact of the device I get the following error and the app crashes:

> plugin com.apple.MobileAddressBook.ContactsViewService interrupted Hub
>   connection error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "The
>   operation couldn’t be completed.... uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM
>   insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

**It's important to say that it is not always happen.. sometimes the contacts open and sometimes I get the above error.**

here is my code to open the contacts:

```
- (IBAction)addContacts:(id)sender {
    self.user = [[User alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"ADD CONTACT");
    _addressBookController = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    [_addressBookController setPeoplePickerDelegate:self];
    [self presentViewController:_addressBookController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

can someone PLEASE point me to the problem?

I add the peoplePickerNavigationController:

```
- (void)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController*)peoplePicker didSelectPerson:(ABRecordRef)person{
    NSLog(@"PEOPLE PICKER");
    CFTypeRef generalCFObject = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    if (generalCFObject) {
        self.user.firstName = (__bridge NSString *)generalCFObject;
        CFRelease(generalCFObject);
    }

    generalCFObject = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
    if (generalCFObject) {
        self.user.lastName = (__bridge NSString *)generalCFObject;
        CFRelease(generalCFObject);
    }

    ABMultiValueRef phonesRef = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
    for (int i=0; i<ABMultiValueGetCount(phonesRef); i++) {
        CFStringRef currentPhoneLabel = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phonesRef, i);
        CFStringRef currentPhoneValue = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phonesRef, i);

        if (CFStringCompare(currentPhoneLabel, kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo) {
            self.user.phoneNumber = (__bridge NSString *)currentPhoneValue;
        }

        CFRelease(currentPhoneLabel);
        CFRelease(currentPhoneValue);
    }

    CFRelease(phonesRef);

    [self.assignment.usersList addObject:self.user];
    [self.tableViewCell reloadData];
    [_addressBookController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}

-(BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier{
    return NO;
}
//enable contact cancel buttopn
-(void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker{
    [_addressBookController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: As is, your code seems fine.  Show us your `ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate` methods.  Might also help to give us the stack dump at the time the exception is thrown.

Comment: @David I re-edit my question and added the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController

Comment: First guess, you have folks in your address book for whom you have no phone numbers.  In that case, `phonesRef` will be nil, so iterating over it (and calling `CFRelease` on it, will fail.  Protect usage of phonesRef as you have the other `ABRecordCopyValue` results.

Comment: Short of that, there's still some relevant missing code (`Users` class, `assignment`

Comment: @David when the app crashes I dont even enter the peoplePicker didSelectPerson func (I tried nslog on the begining of thr finc). so I don't believe this is the problem

Comment: Not a clue then, as is, it's not reproducible.  Have you tried restarting the device?  Are you using device or simulator?

Comment: @David I am using simulator

Comment: Simulator support for Contacts is somewhat problematic, try it on a real device.

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32838772/3099062