# What to do with this message?

Tags: ios, objective-c, abaddressbook

I use iOS 8 objective-c. I receive this message after select contact from contact list.

> plugin com.apple.MobileAddressBook.ContactsViewService invalidated

What to do with this message?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can simply ignore it.
This message just tells you, that the plugin was unloaded by the system.

The same happens when you use 3rd party keyboards while debugging your app when the keyboard has been dismissed.

Comment: Sounds good.  I'd like to up-vote you but I have no way to confirm that nothing bad is happening to my App when I ignore this.  Then I'd be misleading others into thinking I've confirmed this when in fact I don't know.  Do you have any explanation about why this message is benign?

Comment: Its still giving same error in xCode7 GM.. Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score -1):

Ignoring a problem is never a solution (Thyraz).

You are seeing this message in log because in IOS 9 ABPeoplePickerNavigationController is no longer works.

Now there is new library/framework for contacts([CNContact](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Contacts/Reference/CNContact_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CNContact)) which will be used in IOS 9 and above: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Contacts/Reference/Contacts_Framework/index.html

Comment: may I ask you something you said `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` is not available in iOS 9 while I'm developing my app and using it in iOS 9 and it is working fine. Could it be ignored if I submitted to the AppStore?

Comment: it is not true to say that ABPeoplePickerNavigationController "no longer works". 

It has been deprecated, which means there is a newer way to do this, but that does not mean the old way has been retired yet.